# Debian and Ubuntu power management

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, power-management

I use Debian normally, but whenever Ubuntu releases a new version I tend to use it for some time.

In the newer version a lot of changes have been made. In Ubuntu I observed that the backup battery shows 2.15min but the same in Debian shows 1.40min. Can anyone explain why there is a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is not a definitive answer. While the amount of charge of a battery is a definite, known quantity, passed to the computer by the chip on the battery, the estimate duration of a battery charge is done by dividing that quantity by the average energy consumption for a given unit of time.

It might well be that your debian and ubuntu installations have a different record of your battery usage history (e.g. they have a different record of how much energy you typically use in one unit of time).

In some cases it's possible to make the measurament more accurate by actually doing a couple of complete cycles (full charge -> full discharge) while using the computer normally.

An experiment you can do is to actually check if the **actual** duration of the battery is the same under debian and under ubuntu. Should you find that is not the case, than you would know it's not a difference in the recorded data, but some difference in the system configuration that brings to an actual different power usage.

If you will do any of these test, I would be very much interested to hear what was the outcome, as I am a GNU/linux user (various flavours) too!

Answer (score 0):

Like mac said, the estimate remaining battery time is calculated from the average energy consumption of the computer.

What you can do is check under `/proc/acpi/battery` in each OS. Check for files called `info` and `state` and compare the results on both OSes. This should give you a hint on why the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu makes some changes that in Debian are left to the user. However the biggest thing is likely to be that Ubuntu has a newer kernel and other software - there's been a lot of work in reducing power consumption recently. What version of Debian are you using, stable or testing/unstable? [PowerTOP](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/) can be used to see what's causing your CPU to wake up (and hence use energy). That site also has a list of other things that can be tuned to save power.